# Continuous deployment of several services in same solution

Tags: .net, git, azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

So I have a solution in Visual Studio 2015 with several web and application services that I can publish individually to Azure using the publish option.
Now however I would like to automate the deployment (and later add unit testing to the pipeline). I found that I can do this by hosting my solution in a git (or TFS) repository in Visual Studio Team Services and then connect my "project" to an "application service" in Azure. The each time I push my code to git it will trigger a build and deploy it to all azure machines connected to this VSTS project. However, it only seems to work for the project setup as the startup project. 
Is it even possible to setup something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes it is possible**.

If you use [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/), you will need to define different `Artifact` for each component that you want to deploy, and then you can create separate `Releases` for each of those Artifacts to Deploy them to different environments or in different servers.

What you might end up doing is, to have 1 Build definition which builds several projects in a solution and create and copy several Artifacts (if you have 3 different services to deploy you will need at least 3 artifacts) and then create 3 Release definitions to deploy those 3 artifacts.

Technically you could have them all deployed in one Release definition but normally you want the flexibility to be able to deploy each component independently.

Take a look at this document to get more information about the relationship between Builds, Artifacts and Releases:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-artifacts